# Any version of Xcode is not installed/responding on Monterey 12.5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

What's happening:

When it finishes up downloading and I try to open it up, it does not open and says "Application not responding".

What I have done:

- Restarting my Mac
- Reinstalling Xcode (5 different versions for over 20 times) on both the website and AppStore
- Confirming I have more than enough storage

When I tried to use DevCleaner for Xcode, it said "~/Developer folder cannot be found, make sure you've installed Xcode" so I am assuming Xcode was not even installed on my Mac.

Is there anything else I can do to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked if your device meets the Xcode requirements? They can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/)

Comment: I appreciate you for answering! My Mac is M1 Air 2020, runs the latest version of Montrey. I just checked the Xcode requirements and confirmed my Mac meets them.

Comment: I know this version of Xcode is different but [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/409026/xcode-12-3-is-not-responding-a-few-seconds-after-opening-it) post may help. Let me know.

Comment: Are you installing via AppStore or downloading the .dmg file directly? I would recommend not using the AppStore if you're doing so, and download directly from apple: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

Comment: @johnny I have tried both, I installed multiple versions of Xcode on the website to see if any of them work but none of them did.